# Ambiguous reference to member "text"

Tags: swift, string, compiler-errors, iboutlet

I have two `IBOulets`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
```

and I want to check if their textfields are blank or not. However, when I invoke the text.isBlank method the compiler shows error `"Ambiguous reference to member 'text'"`

```
   if ChatManager.shared.isConnected() {
        ChatManager.shared.disconnect()
        usernameTextField.isHidden = false
        passwordTextField.isHidden = false

    } else {


        guard usernameTextField.text.isBlank == false,
            passwordTextField.text.isBlank == false else {
            return
        }
```

I also noticed that UITextfield has text : String? or text(UITextRange) : String?

Comment: can you tell me exactly what does `isBlank` property do?

Comment: If your want to check for `empty` string, the designated mechanism is `.isEmpty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was because my OS and Xcode versions were not up to date. After i updated to sierra and used swift 3.1 the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
else {
    guard usernameTextField.text.isEmpty == false,
    passwordTextField.text.isEmpty == false else {
    return
}
```